# How to add Fade to effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, fadeto

I have 3 images, and I need to do the following,

1. when I click on `image1` ---> background color/opacity of `image2` & `image3` will change.
2. Again I click on `image2` --->background color/opacity  of `image1` & `image3` will change.
3. Again I click on `image3` --->background color/opacity  of `image1` & `image2` will change.

Is it possible?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You'll need a jQuery color animation plugin (jQuery itself doesn't animate color values), such as the one in jQuery UI. Then simply make the background of the images transparent and get a background color to a container behind each image, and use `animate` to animate the background color, changing it from one value to another, e.g.:

```
$("selector for the background").animate({
    backgroundColor: "target color" // Requires plugin, see above
});
```

```js
$(".target").delay(250).animate({
  backgroundColor: "#FEFE00"
}, 1500);
```

```css
.target {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="target">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLYDl.png">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: which plugin can i use for it?  @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @MD.ShahabUddin: *"...such as the one built into jQuery UI..."* Or just search for "jQuery color animation plugin".

Comment: 3 image will stay in one line .example :                                                   [image1[image2[image3]    .                                                                              image1 ---> background color of image2 & image3 will change. Again i will click on image2 --->background color of image1 & image3 will change. again i will click on image3 --->background color of image1 & image2 will change              @ T.J. Crowder

Comment: @MD.ShahabUddin: You just have to put different container elements behind them, and animate the color of the relevant container elements when changing things.